# in Python, why use "val = param or None' when you can take default params?

Tags: python

I found some examples like below:

```py
def some_func(param):
    inner_var = param or None
    # rest of codes...
```

This is used in class as well:

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, param):
        self.param = param or None
```

But why use this way, when you can simply use default param syntax?
For example,

```py
def some_func(param=None):
    # just use param
```

like this! also, are there any difference depending on the value after "or"?

Comment: The behavior is not actually the same.  None isn't the only falsey value.

Comment: `param or None` has the effect of converting all falsey values (empty string, empty list, numeric zero, etc.) to `None`.

Comment: Also with the former you still have to pass a `param` (even if it is just a falsy value) while in the latter it's optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically they are converting all non-truthy values to `None`. So the `val` variable is only ever truthy values or `None` — never falsy values other than `None`.

For purposes of having a default value, you should use the latter (third code example) is what you should use — that allows you to avoid needlessly taking in a falsy value only for it to be converted to `None`.

Comment: _"For your purposes the latter (third code example) is what you should use."_: Out of curiosity, how did you know what OP's purposes are?

Comment: @Selcuk they asked why do this "when you can take default params" which implies they are looking at this as an alternate to default params

Comment: Fair assumption, but it is still likely that they just don't know the difference (hence the question) and actually need the first method.

Comment: @Selcuk Because I wasn't aware of any other purpose lol. That's why I asked this question.

Answer (score 1):

The other difference is that in the original, callers are required to provide an argument when calling the function.  With your proposed change, this would no longer be the case.